# Building search to the website

Tags: php, search, lucene, search-engine

I have a website which has about 200 to 300 static public pages. I am required to bring about some kind of search functionality on the website which will search all of its public pages. I don't want to use external tools like Google site search, etc. Is there a tool or open source code that will index the content and then display the search results? I am looking for a tool that will maintain its own index and run on the server along with the website. If I can add items to the index and manage it that would be a plus. I have looked at Zend Search Lucene, if there is a tool out there, I am hoping to use it before I make one myself.

Comment: Lucene and Solr are pretty much the right tools for the job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Zend_Search_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html) is a very good choice. It is compatible with the Java version of Lucene (I mean the index files). It [can index html documents](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html#zend.search.lucene.index-creation.html-documents), it's quite simple to use and configure and has a good documentation.
- Using [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) as a service is an option as well.
- [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) is another tool you might want to look at.

Comment: All three tools Emil mentioned can probably do the job. I believe you should choose among them according to their learning curve for you (Zend_Search_Lucene complements an existing PHP code base, Solr is a stand-alone search server easy to set up; Sphinx I believe to be similar to Solr in the set up respect).

Answer (score 1):

You can try -

Sphider is a lightweight web spider and search engine written in PHP, using MySQL as its back end database. It is a great tool for adding search functionality to your web site or building your custom search engine. Sphider is small, easy to set up and modify, and is used in thousands of websites across the world.

http://www.sphider.eu/